# Why does mental work cause fatigue?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience

In Mental Fatigue: Costs and Benefits, Boksem and Tops advance that mental fatigue results from the brain's decision to save energy:

[image]

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51426280_Mental_fatigue_Costs_and_benefits

Yet, on "Time", Dr Marcus Raichle argues that: "while the brain burns a lot of energy, any changes in brain activity and energy use during a tough mental task are minute".

([https://time.com/5400025/does-thinking-burn-calories/#:~:text=While%20the%20brain%20represents%20just,way%20the%20brain%20consumes%20energy.](https://time.com/5400025/does-thinking-burn-calories/#:%7E:text=While%20the%20brain%20represents%20just,way%20the%20brain%20consumes%20energy.))

Considering these statements, if mental work does not consume large amounts of energy and mental fatigue is caused by energy investment, why does mental work cause fatigue?